# Как отправить значения полей не указанных в коде страницы?

Tags: php, javascript

На странице есть кнопка которая добавляет 2 поля через JS на эту же страницу не перезагружая ее. В коде страницы они не отображаются. Я не могу отправить их в БД. Как их обработать?

Comment: Как вариант, добавлять не в поля значения, а создавать поля уже со значениями!

Comment: провтыкал с вопрос... пардон.

Answer (score 1):

если эти поля имеют уникальный атрибут name и находятся в теле формы, то они отправляются на сервер, возможно ты их создал вне формы, попробуй найти их по коду инспектором

Comment: как я понял, речь идет о hidden полях

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я нашел ошибку. Я тупица не заполнял поля , а следовательно самих переменных нет. Когда заполнил все отправилось. Теперь надо сделать чтоб таких полей добавлялось несколько. В sql запросе надо указать столько полей, сколько добавил на страницу.